# ErrorException: Array to string conversion. When trying to createMany() on a hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I've been screwing around with this a lot and can not seem to figure it out. I scraped foursquare for their categories and am trying to use them to seed categories in my DB. I am using PHP and Laravel.

**Here is the code for the CategorySeeder:**

```
class CategorySeeder extends Seeder
{
public function run()
{
    $categories = json_decode(file_get_contents('foursquare_categories.json', true), true);

    foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
        $this->createCategory($category);
    }
}

private function createCategory($categoryData)
{
    try
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $category = Category::where('name', $categoryData['name'])->first();

        if (!$category)
        {
            $category = new Category();
            $category->fill([
                'name' => $categoryData['name']
            ]);
            $category->save();
        }

        $category->childCategories()->createMany($categoryData['sub_categories']);

        DB::commit();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        DB::rollBack();
    }

    if (count($categoryData['sub_categories']) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($categoryData['sub_categories'] as $subCategory)
        {
            if (count($subCategory['sub_categories']) > 0)
            {
                $this->createCategory($subCategory);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Here is the stack trace log:**

```
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(231): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Array to string...', '/var/www/html/v...', 674)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php(674): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}(2, 'Array to string...', '/var/www/html/v...', 674)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.php(57): Illuminate\Support\Str::replaceArray('?', Array, 'insert into `ca...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.php(40): Illuminate\Database\QueryException->formatMessage('insert into `ca...', Array, Object(PDOException))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(717): Illuminate\Database\QueryException->__construct('insert into `ca...', Array, Object(PDOException))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(676): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `ca...', Array, Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(502): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('insert into `ca...', Array, Object(Closure))
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(454): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement('insert into `ca...', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php(32): Illuminate\Database\Connection->insert('insert into `ca...', Array)
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3170): Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor->processInsertGetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder), 'insert into `ca...', Array, 'id')
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1707): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->insertGetId(Array, 'id')
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1190): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('insertGetId', Array)
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1155): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->insertAndSetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Array)
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(996): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->performInsert(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php(309): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(302): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany->Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\{closure}(Object(App\Models\Category))
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php(310): tap(Object(App\Models\Category), Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php(324): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany->create(Array)
#18 /var/www/html/database/seeders/CategorySeeder.php(47): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany->createMany(Array)
#19 /var/www/html/database/seeders/CategorySeeder.php(68): Database\Seeders\CategorySeeder->createCategory(Array)
#20 /var/www/html/database/seeders/CategorySeeder.php(68): Database\Seeders\CategorySeeder->createCategory(Array)
#21 /var/www/html/database/seeders/CategorySeeder.php(25): Database\Seeders\CategorySeeder->createCategory(Array)
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Database\Seeders\CategorySeeder->run()
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(175): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array, Array)
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(184): Illuminate\Database\Seeder->Illuminate\Database\{closure}()
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php(75): Illuminate\Database\Seeder->__invoke()
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php(155): Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand->Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\{closure}()
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php(76): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::unguarded(Object(Closure))
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand->handle()
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(291): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(989): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(299): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(102): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#44 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#45 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#46 {main}
```

It is occurring when trying to run the `createMany()` I know that much I am just unsure why it is failing.

**Lastly, here is the json file I am reading (Feel free to copy it and use it if you need categories):**

https://file.io/3qWs6s5IMv5a

Comment: The crazy thing is it works fine in tinker the exact same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I SOLVED IT**

So I switched `$category->childCategories()->createMany($categoryData['sub_categories']);` to this

```
foreach ($categoryData['sub_categories'] as $subCategory)
{
    $subCategory['parent_id'] = $category->id;
    unset($subCategory['sub_categories']);

    Category::create($subCategory);
}
```

What was causing the error was apparently passing the 'sub_categories' of a sub_category. I am still unclear as to why though I do not have sub_categories as a fillable column on the Category Model.